# How to Import Excel File to Microsoft Access 2013

Tags: sql, vba, ms-access, ms-access-2013

I have an Access 2013 database with all tables linked to SQL Server 2016 tables. I have an Excel 2013 (.xlsx) file, that I need to import into a a table in Ms Access that is linked to SQL Server via vba Code (all fields in xlsx and table are the same)

All my VBA code resides in the Access database, I have a form with a button with event in it, I try to use de "transferspreadsheet", an "Insert to" Clause for sql but neither of them has worked for me

Here is my code,

xtRuta2 name of the field in the form that have the path
Dim strArchivo2 String ' path of the file xlsx c:\reports\mireporte.xlsx
dim miAlerta2 as string
Dim ssql As String

strArchivo2 = txtRuta2

miAlerta2 = MsgBox("¿Do you want to import new information for " & strArchivo2 & "?" & vbCrLf & vbCrLf & "This operation will be update all the information", vbExclamation + vbOKCancel, "¡INFORMATION IMPORT ALERT!")

If miAlerta2 = vbOK Then
    varAlert2 = MsgBox("Please confirm you want to import new information?", vbExclamation + vbOKCancel, "¡CONFIRMATION IMPORT ALERT!")
    If varAlert2 = vbOK Then

```
      'DoCmd.TransferSpreadsheet acImport, acSpreadsheetTypeExcel12, "tbl_ZSales_Export Worksheet", strArchivo2, True, "Export Worksheet$"

            ssql = "INSERT INTO [tbl_Export Worksheet] select * FROM OPENROWSET('Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0', 'Excel 12.0;Database=" & strArchivo2 & ";HDR=YES', 'SELECT * FROM [Export Worksheet$)'"

            'CurrentDb.Execute ssql

    MsgBox "Import Finished", vbExclamation + vbOKOnly
```

endif
end if

Can you please help me to write the correct code for this to work

Thanks regards!

Comment: what are your errors?

Comment: the error said:
Error 3131 en proc. cmdImportar2_Click de Documento VBA form_frmImprtar (Syntax error in FROM clause.)

Comment: Im pretty sure Access sql doesnt support open rowset.

Comment: OK, what should be the correct code?

Answer (score 0):

This piece of code (late bdingin interaction with excel) is used to convert excel sheet to text file and then import to a table of your choosing. I prefer to use this method as access has an annoying habit of trying ot interpret your data for you when using transferspreadsheet. With creating an import spec (which you need to do to use this method), you can easily predefine the data types.

```
Option Compare Database
Option Explicit

Private Sub stuff()
    On Error GoTo GetAccrualFile_Err
    Dim fileLoc As String
    Dim path As String, Sep As String, NewTextFile As String, WholeLine As String
    Dim oXL As Object, sheet As Object
    Dim i As Long, j As Long, counteri As Long, counterj As Long
    Dim bringOver As Variant
    DoCmd.SetWarnings False
    DoCmd.Hourglass True
    counteri = 0
    counterj = 0
    Sep ="your prefered delimiter"
    DoCmd.RunSQL "DELETE * FROM TBL"
    fileLoc = "UNC PATH AND FILE NAME" & ".xlsx"
    path = Left(fileLoc, InStrRev(fileLoc, "\") - 1) & "\"
    NewTextFile = "UNC PATH AND FILE NAME" & ".txt"
    Set oXL = CreateObject("Excel.Application")
    With oXL
        .WorkBooks.Open FileName:=path & Dir$(fileLoc)
        Open NewTextFile For Output As #2
        bringOver = .Worksheets("your sheet name").UsedRange  'you might need to adjust this line to get the sheet your after
        For i = LBound(bringOver, 1) To UBound(bringOver, 1)
            For j = LBound(bringOver, 2) To UBound(bringOver, 2)
                WholeLine = WholeLine & bringOver(i, j) & Sep
                counterj = counterj + 1
            Next j
            'used if you want to skip column headers
            If counteri <> 0 Then
                Print #2, WholeLine
            End If
            WholeLine = ""
            counteri = counteri + 1
            counterj = 0
        Next i
        counteri = 0
        Erase bringOver
    End With    
    Close #2
    DoCmd.TransferText acImportDelim, "importspecname", "tbltoimportto", NewTextFile, False
    '***************************************************************************************
    'you will need to learn how to set up import specs, as well as understand the arguments for DoCmd.TransferText  
    '***************************************************************************************
CleanUp:
    DoCmd.SetWarnings True
    DoCmd.Hourglass False
    On Error Resume Next
    DoEvents
    oXL.Quit
    oXL.Application.Quit
    If Dir(NewTextFile) <> "" Then Kill NewTextFile
    Erase bringOver
    DoCmd.SetWarnings True
    DoCmd.Hourglass False
    Exit Sub
GetAccrualFile_Err:
    DoCmd.SetWarnings True
    DoCmd.Hourglass False
    msgbox "An error has occured.  " & " " & ERR.Number & " " & ERR.Description & " "
    GoTo CleanUp
    Resume
End Sub
```

Comment: The problem with this is that I have the table linked with sql server, and don't accept the transfertext or TransferSpreadsheet, thats what I need a sql code that Insert the file into the table linked

Comment: When I use de Transfertext or TransferSpreadSheet method, what Ms Access is doing is creating a New Table and not are appending (Insert to) the data to the linked table I Have.

Comment: well then insert into a new table, then use sql to select * into other table. Seems like a simple work aorund

Comment: That's what I don't want, I think it must have code with the right method to insert the data in the sql linked table correctly

Comment: IDK why you think this wont work? Transfer text appends by default. I do this all the time with file loads. It does work and my preferred method due to access quarks.

Comment: Because when I run it I get an Error or the mechanie stays thinking (working) and dont do anything, as you say I thought it was simple, import, add and ready but I test many codes and methods and I can solve it, really I dont know what is the problema,

Comment: Did you even try setting up an import spec and try this? im guessing not

Comment: Well, I don't know if is my version of Microsoft Access or not, but when I have linked tables to sql server (back-end) and I try to import / append to create the specification the button to save the specif don't appears,, that means that I can't create a specification to import. This only happend when we have Linked tables to sql,

Comment: try this link https://access-programmers.com/creating-an-import-specification-in-access-2003

Comment: Ok, return with this problem,  I was looking for and I have these two
1-
DoCmd.TransferSpreadsheet acImport, acSpreadsheetTypeExcel12, "tbl_Export Worksheet", strArchivo2, True, "Export Worksheet$"
2-
txtSQL = "INSERT INTO [tbl_ZSales_Export Worksheet] " & _
"SELECT * FROM [Excel 12.0;HDR=YES;DATABASE=" _
& strArchivo2
DoCmd.RunSQL txtSQL

Both do not give an error, but it leaves me the machine worked, it seems that it is doing something, but it remains hours thinking, what could be the problem? How could I correct it?

Comment: I'm using Microsoft Access - Excel 2013

Answer (score -1):

Try EPPlus, a free library which allows you to manage Excel files from .Net platform.
Here you have a tutorial: https://riptutorial.com/epplus

Comment: This is a comment to the original question, not an answer.